# How to move logs out of journalctl, to a file with daily rotation & archiving?

Tags: 16.04, systemd, logging

I have a particular custom service registered in systemd, which spews a lot of logs to stdout/stderr. I want to **remove the logs from journalctl output** (because they generate a lot of noise there, and also sometimes get "rotated" and deleted by journald) **into a file** in /var/log/. I also want to setup log rotation & compression for it (ideally, a **daily rotation + compression**, with archive files **older than N last days deleted**).

I don't know how to configure this in Ubuntu 16.04. I tried to google it up, but was surprised I was not able to find a sensible solution to my situation. Here's how I tried to approach the design, each time however with serious disadvantages:

### Idea 1: rsyslog + ...what?

Based on [an answer + extra comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585758/how-to-redirect-output-of-systemd-service-to-a-file#comment89744385_43830129) on stackoverflow, I understood that the "recommended elegant solution" to **copy logs from journalctl to file** seems to be to:

1. Add a `SyslogIdentifier=<CUSTOM_ID>` in my *.service file;
2. Create `/etc/rsyslog.d/<CUSTOM_NAME>.conf` with contents like below:

   ```
   :programname, isequal, "<CUSTOM_ID>" /var/log/<CUSTOM_LOG>.log
   ```

However, this seems to have two disadvantages for me:

- journalctl output still noisy,
- no log rotation.

### Idea 2: rsyslog + logrotate? but how?

Continuing with Idea 1, trying to add rotation: based on googling for rsyslog + rotate, I found an article which mentions that [rsyslog has some basic support for log rotation](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/log_rotation_fix_size.html). However, this seems to require additionally writing a **custom shell script** to do the actual rotation, once logs reach the rotation criterion. And I'm not yet even sure if this allows for the criterion to be date-based.

I would prefer to avoid creating a custom shell script for log rotation, when there's already **logrotate**. But I don't understand if it's possible to configure logrotate to use it here **in place of the "custom script"**. All I could find about logrotate seems to be focused on running it globally for the whole OS, not for this kind of one-shot usage with rsyslog... So **I don't know how to complete this idea.** :/

### Idea 3: shell redirection + ...what?

I'm thinking to fall back to the old & ugly shell redirection as the "logging mechanism", as this would solve my issue with journalctl output being noisy.

However, apart from this being "not elegant" and generally "you should feel guilty for doing this, bad bad boy", I still don't know how to configure **log rotation** well in such case...

### Summary

I'm really confused and seriously disappointed that there doesn't seem to be an easy way to configure this, which to me feels like a  really obvious situation which I'd think should be common and have a simple answer.

**Can you help me configure this?**

Or am I maybe missing something?